# From LANGUAGE DESIGN level, why doesn't "if constexpr" decay to "trival if" when condition cannot be deduced at compile-time

Tags: c++, constexpr, if-constexpr

As we know, when `constexpr function`'s return value cannot be known at `compile-time`, it will be delayed to be computed at `run-time`(IOW, decay to `non-constexpr function`). This allows us to adhere `constexpr` to a function freely and need not worry about any overhead.

I think it can also apply to `if statement`. Since c++17, we have `if constexpr`, so we can use `compile-time if statement` easily(without `true_type`/`false_type`. Unlike `constexpr function`, however, it will fail if its condition cannot be known at compile-time:

```
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    if constexpr(n == 0) return 1;
    else return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

So, the codes above [cannot pass compilation](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b4n84LGYaXjTnZZs) because `n` is not a constant expression. But certainly, [the function can be calculated at `compile-time` when input is known at compile-time](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OGnrS9ZTfaoXUyqG).

Comment: I think your example might be made more compelling by using a `constexpr int factorial` function with a `constexpr if (v==0)`.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks! Edited that in.

Comment: @陳力 Like your example code you don't need `if constexpr`.  A regular `if` is all that is needed.  The main use of `if constexpr` is when the branch that would not be executed would not compile.

Comment: [quora](https://www.quora.com/From-a-language-design-level-why-doesnt-if-constexpr-decay-to-trival-if-when-the-condition-cannot-be-deduced-at-compile-time/answer/Joe-Zbiciak?__filter__=&__nsrc__=2&__snid3__=2745481457) has an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason that swallowing errors/exceptions and just plowing through is bad. It can potentially put your program in some sort of unspecified state. Making it almost impossible to reason about.

If a constraint in a program isn't met, the person who wrote it and relied on it *needs* to be notified promptly. Making such a thing a hard error for a language construct makes sense. Especially if the language construct drive the actual generation of code.

In this case the constraint is `b` being a valid constant expression.